# With performance in mind, how should I get an ObjectWriter for serializing POJOs to JSON?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jackson-databind

The [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper JavaDocs](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) say:

> Mapper instances are fully thread-safe provided that ALL configuration
>   of the instance occurs before ANY read or write calls. If
>   configuration of a mapper instance is modified after first usage,
>   changes may or may not take effect, and configuration calls themselves
>   may fail. If you need to use different configuration, you have two
>   main possibilities:
>
> Construct and use ObjectReader for reading, ObjectWriter for writing.
>   Both types are fully immutable and you can freely create new instances
>   with different configuration using either factory methods of
>   ObjectMapper, or readers/writers themselves. Construction of new
>   ObjectReaders and ObjectWriters is a very light-weight operation so it
>   is usually appropriate to create these on per-call basis, as needed,
>   for configuring things like optional indentation of JSON.

Is it OK to make this call every time I need a new ObjectWriter?

```
jsonString = new MyObjectWriter().objectWriter().writeValueAsString(myPojo);
```

Where MyObjectWriter looks like this:

```
public class MyObjectWriter {
    public ObjectWriter objectWriter()
    {
        return new ObjectMapper()
                .writer()
                .with(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
                .with(JsonGenerator.Feature.IGNORE_UNKNOWN);
    }
}
```

Should I hang on to a copy of the ObjectMapper? The ObjectWriter?

Comment: No, you should hold on to the instance of `ObjectMapper`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like documentation says this is really cheap operation and you can do that "on per call basis". Let's see what we have behind each method.

- `ObjectMapper.writer` - creates new `ObjectWriter` using `SerializationConfig` from `ObjectMapper`.
- `ObjectWriter.with` - creates new `ObjectWriter` which is based on `caller` instance plus new feature which must be enabled. In case given feature is already enabled the same instance is returned. If feature changes configuration - new `ObjectWriter` is created and returned.

Let's see example application which shows given scenario:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ObjectWriter writer0 = mapper.writer();
        ObjectWriter writer1 = writer0.with(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        ObjectWriter writer2 = writer1.with(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        ObjectWriter writer3 = writer2.with(JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS);

        Map<String, Long> map = Collections.singletonMap("key", 123L);
        System.out.println(writer0 + " = " + writer0.writeValueAsString(map));
        System.out.println(writer1 + " = " + writer1.writeValueAsString(map));
        System.out.println(writer2 + " = " + writer2.writeValueAsString(map));
        System.out.println(writer3 + " = " + writer3.writeValueAsString(map));


        ObjectMapper mapper1 = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper1.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        mapper1.enable(JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS);

        ObjectWriter writer4 = mapper1.writer();
        System.out.println(writer4 + " = " + writer4.writeValueAsString(map));
    }
}
```

Above app prints:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter@2ed94a8b = {"key":123}
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter@2a5ca609 = {
  "key" : 123
}
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter@2a5ca609 = {
  "key" : 123
}
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter@20e2cbe0 = {
  "key" : "123"
}

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter@68be2bc2 = {
  "key" : "123"
}
```

Notice, that second (`writer1`) and third (`writer2`) instances (`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter@2a5ca609`) are the same. They also generate the same `JSON` payload.

So, using first instance of `ObjectMapper` we created and configured `ObjectWriter`. But mainly only the last one is used. All in between are already gone and wait for collecting by `GC`. There is no point to do that. It is better to create `ObjectMapper` instance, configure it and create `ObjectWriter` already configured by calling `writer()` method. You can create `Factory`-like class for configured instances of `ObjectMapper` and you can use these instances to generate `ObjectWriter`-s.

Comment: So I could create a

`private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();`

Then have my `objectWriter()` method

`return mapper.writer().with(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT).with(JsonGenerator.Feature.IGNORE_UNKNOWN);`

Then any callers that don't change the features will get the same ObjectWriter instance.  Correct?

Comment: @braveterry, every time you invoke method `objectWriter() {return mapper.writer().with(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT).with(JsonGenerator.Feature.IGNORE_UNKNOWN);}` new `ObjectWriter` instance will be returned. It is much better to create `ObjectMapper` instance with these features and your method could look like this: `objectWriter() {return mapper.writer();}`. Every time you call this method you will get new instance of `ObjectWriter`. The main point is that during invoking chain-calling `mapper.writer().with(FEATURE1).with(FEATURE2)...` we create many `ObjectWriter`-es behind scene.